# What is the best way to iterate dictionary keys in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

What is the best way to iterate dictionary keys in Python? should I use the keys() function or not?
for example:

```
for k in dict:
      do somthing
```

Or

```
for k in dict.keys():
      do somthing
```

Comment: it's up to you, it's your choices

Comment: Either. But actually, the first one.